# Vuex - TypeScript mapGetters

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I am having trouble understanding how `mapGetters` work with TypeScript. I am following the examples [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/109) but can't get it to work using the suggestions

here is my code

**getters.ts**

```
export const GET_POSTS = 'GET_POSTS'
```

**posts.module**

```
import {GET_POSTS} from '../types/getters'
...
  get [GET_POSTS]() {
    return this.posts || [];
  }
```

**PostsList.vue**

```
@Component({
  components: { PostListItem },
  computed: mapGetters(["GET_POSTS"]) // what local prop does this map to or how do I access it?
})
export default class PostsList extends Vue {
  name = "PostsList";
  posts = [];

  /**
   * Get posts
   */
  async mounted() {
   console.log(this.GET_POSTS); // ERROR: Property 'GET_POSTS' does not exist on type 'PostsList'.
  }
```

essentially, I'm trying to do:

```
...mapGetters({
   posts: GET_POSTS
})

console.log(this.posts)
```

Answer (score 0):

The referred issue [suggests the solution](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/109#issuecomment-447201746). Since there is no way for Vue class components to infer types for members, mapped Vuex item should be asserted:

It should be:

```
GET_POSTS!: () => PostInterface[];
posts: PostInterface[] = [];
```

The assertion requires a developer to be responsible for provided type. In case `mapGetters(["GET_POSTS"])` is missing or doesn't conform to provided type expected, this will result in runtime error.

Vue class components are expected to be deprecated. Composition API provides better support for TypeScript.